# Audio editing in  Android 

Tags: android, audio

I am looking for some audio editing library which can help to mix two audio files into a single audio file. I don't mean concatenating file one after other.
I want to mix second audio file in middle of random seek time of the first file as follow.

Track T1 :  1111111111
 Track T2 :  2222

Output expected : 11112222111111

I want to achieve this for android application.

Comment: Can you not create a third audio file , add 1111, then append 2222 and then the remaining 111111 ??

Comment: @Rihan I am searching for the same library which can give me functionality to split the file into two and then i can concate those 3 files one after other. And i need to port this for my BB app

Comment: what format is your file in ? mp3? amr?

Comment: When you say "mix" what is your desired output, audio out of the blackberry speakers or a WAV file?

Comment: a WAV file , or an audio file in any of the supported format amr,wav or mp3

Comment: @JavalNanda I need to overlap(not concatenate one after another) two or more mp3 files . May be you know how to do that in android as you worked with audio file formats in android. I have searched alot about overlaping mp3 files but no luck. Hope you have solution for my problem . Thank you Javal

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only interesting and useful library I have found for audio editing is Ringdroid (available here: [RingDroid Github](https://github.com/google/ringdroid)).

You can check the source code in order to get some insights on how to do what you want.

Hope this helps for now!

Comment: @Dimitris...You have any clue how to use this for sound processing?

Comment: Hi, Ringdroid is an amazing Project. I just want to ask, if there is any Example of Merging 2 Audio Files. I have downloaded the Source provided on Google Code, But it doesn't have any Method for Merging Sound Files. Any help is Highly Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The description of this  project looks promising:  [musicg-sound-api](http://code.google.com/p/musicg/) .

> This API allows developers to extract audio features and operate audio
>   data like reading, cutting and trimming easily from an inputstream

However, the documentation is a little sparse.