# Audio song mixer in android programmatically

Tags: android, audio, audio-player

I want to create an audio mixer (DJ music track) kind  of app which can create Dj mixer of an audio song. User can select a music song track that can be mixed with two or more separate rhythm, bass or beat tracks to create a new modified Dj music.

I did a lot of research over this but could not find any idea or clue.

If anyone have some idea or some reference URL regarding this, please share it.

Comment: Still waiting for any clue  ..... :(

Answer (score 18):

There is no build-in library on Android that supports audio mixing (combining two audio input streams into one output stream). The Java `javax.sound` library which supports audio mixing was not ported to Android - there's an interesting [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/VD2V7ENFrgs) on Google Groups with Google engineer Diane Hackborn about the decision to not port `javax.sound` to Android.

It looks like you have to develop your own solution from scratch. There are several helpful answers on SO on how to combine two audio streams into one:

[Mixing Audio Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191408/mixing-audio-files)

[Audio editing in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265494/audio-editing-in-android)

[Android - Mixing multiple static waveforms into a single AudioTrack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820802/android-mixing-multiple-static-waveforms-into-a-single-audiotrack)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the hardest part of this would be playing multiple tracks at once, and that the rest can be done with the UI. One link that might help you is [How to play multiple ogg or mp3 at the same time..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9866927/how-to-play-multiple-ogg-or-mp3-at-the-same-time) The documentation for SoundPool, which lets you play multiple sounds at once, can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html).

Comment: Thanks Dare for the reply... But I don't think soundPool is a right  choice to create mixed sound of multiple tracks...as we need to mix the songs,beats,rhythm,bass in a single track (I mean as a single output track). Let me know your view over this ....!!!

Comment: It seems that if you want a single output track, you just need to add the tracks together and correct for clipping. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126169/programmatically-merging-two-pieces-of-audio

Answer (score 0):

It is late but if someone needs, [AudioMixer-android](https://github.com/rajib010/android_audio_mixer) can be used.

Comment: Does this support setting volume balance (panning) on individual tracks when mixing?

Answer (score -1):

```
File dir;
dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
dir.mkdirs();

//Audio Mixer for two .raw file into single .wav file...
void AudioMixer() {
    File file_play1 = new File(dir, "Neww.raw");
    int shortSizeInBytes = Short.SIZE / Byte.SIZE;
    int bufferSizeInBytes = (int) (file_play1.length() / shortSizeInBytes);
    short[] audioData = new short[bufferSizeInBytes];

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file_play1);
        BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
        DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(bufferedInputStream);

        InputStream inputStream1 = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.trainss); //Play form raw folder
        BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream1 = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream1);
        DataInputStream dataInputStream1 = new DataInputStream(bufferedInputStream1);

        int i = 0;
        while (dataInputStream.available() > 0 && dataInputStream1.available() > 0) {
            audioData[i] = (short) (dataInputStream.readShort() + dataInputStream1.readShort());
            i++;
        }

        dataInputStream.close();
        dataInputStream1.close();
        AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(
                AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                11025,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                bufferSizeInBytes,
                AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
        audioTrack.write(audioData, 0, bufferSizeInBytes);

        //merge two .raw files in  single .raw file...
        File file_record = new File(dir, "testing.raw");
        try {
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file_record);
            BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream);
            DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(bufferedOutputStream);

            for (int j = 0; j < audioData.length; j++) {
                dataOutputStream.writeShort(audioData[j]);
            }
            dataOutputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Convert that .raw (testing.raw) file into .wav (testingNew.wav) file 
        File des = new File(dir, "testingNew.wav");
        try {
            rawToWave(file_record, des);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//convert .raw file to .wav File...
private void rawToWave(final File rawFile, final File waveFile) throws IOException {
    byte[] rawData = new byte[(int) rawFile.length()];
    DataInputStream input = null;
    try {
        input = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(rawFile));
        input.read(rawData);
    } finally {
        if (input != null) {
            input.close();
        }
    }

    DataOutputStream output = null;
    try {
        output = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(waveFile));
        // WAVE header
        writeString(output, "RIFF"); // chunk id
        writeInt(output, 36 + rawData.length); // chunk size
        writeString(output, "WAVE"); // format
        writeString(output, "fmt "); // subchunk 1 id
        writeInt(output, 16); // subchunk 1 size
        writeShort(output, (short) 1); // audio format (1 = PCM)
        writeShort(output, (short) 1); // number of channels
        writeInt(output, SAMPLE_RATE); // sample rate
        writeInt(output, SAMPLE_RATE * 2); // byte rate
        writeShort(output, (short) 2); // block align
        writeShort(output, (short) 16); // bits per sample
        writeString(output, "data"); // subchunk 2 id
        writeInt(output, rawData.length); // subchunk 2 size
        // Audio data (conversion big endian -> little endian)
        short[] shorts = new short[rawData.length / 2];
        ByteBuffer.wrap(rawData).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer().get(shorts);
        ByteBuffer bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(shorts.length * 2);
        for (short s : shorts) {
            bytes.putShort(s);
        }
        output.write(bytes.array());
    } finally {
        if (output != null) {
            output.close();
        }
    }
}

private void writeInt(final DataOutputStream output, final int value) throws IOException {
    output.write(value >> 0);
    output.write(value >> 8);
    output.write(value >> 16);
    output.write(value >> 24);
}

private void writeShort(final DataOutputStream output, final short value) throws IOException {
    output.write(value >> 0);
    output.write(value >> 8);
}

private void writeString(final DataOutputStream output, final String value) throws IOException {
    for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++) {
        output.write(value.charAt(i));
    }
}


//playing merged file...
private void playWavFile() {
    MediaPlayer recorded_audio_in_sounds = new MediaPlayer();
    String outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/testingNew.wav";
    try {
        if (recorded_audio_in_sounds != null) {
            if (recorded_audio_in_sounds.isPlaying()) {
                recorded_audio_in_sounds.pause();
                recorded_audio_in_sounds.stop();
                recorded_audio_in_sounds.reset();
                recorded_audio_in_sounds.setDataSource(outputFile);
                recorded_audio_in_sounds.prepare();
                recorded_audio_in_sounds.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                recorded_audio_in_sounds.start();
                recorded_audio_in_sounds.start();
            } else {
                recorded_audio_in_sounds.reset();
                recorded_audio_in_sounds.setDataSource(outputFile);
                recorded_audio_in_sounds.prepare();
                recorded_audio_in_sounds.start();
                recorded_audio_in_sounds.setVolume(2.0f, 2.0f);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, you should add some information to your answer, such as where you got the code and what it is doing.