# Can USB microphone & device's speakers work simultaneously?

Tags: android, audio, audio-route

Long story short, I just wanted to know if it's possible (and how) to have as audio input some external device (like USB microphone) but at the same time, as output the device's speaker/s ?

Use case example : video conference.

I managed to make it work only one of the two.. I noticed that in order for the USB microphone to work I have to use `audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false)`, which obviously is not of much help in my case since I need the speakers to output the conference audio streams.

Thanks in advance for any guidance into this.

Comment: What you're looking for is "mixing."

Comment: For example: https://www.androidauthority.com/best-dj-apps-for-android-622809/

Comment: For coding purposes, there might be some help here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228196/audio-song-mixer-in-android-programmatically

Comment: Hey, thank you for answer. But I am not sure that this is what I was looking for..

Comment: If you want to output two streams of audio at the same time (the conference audio stream and the microphone), you need to *mix* them.

Comment: You got me wrong.. I don't want to output two audio streams. Think about the case of a conference. I want the USB microphone to be the audio input, and the output from speakers :D So basically I want to hear through the speakers but speak into the usb microphone

Comment: What are you planning to use for the speaker?  A bluetooth device?

Comment: No, just the built in speakers. Just as you are turning the speakers ON, on a phone call

Comment: That's not going to work.  The speaker and the microphone are too close to each other; you'll get feedback.  The reason a speakerphone works is because of something called "echo cancellation."  And the speaker in an android device doesn't produce enough output to be useful.  Have a look here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.petenotpete.myapplication&hl=en_US

Comment: Yes and no. The input from the microphone won't be sent to the same device speakers..